# Merge two arrays from a JSON file using jq

Tags: arrays, json, jq

I have a JSON file with the following code:

```json
{
  "fruits": [
    {
      "name": "banana"
    },
    {
      "name": "apple"
    }
  ],
  "vegetables": [
    {
      "name": "tomato"
    },
    {
      "name": "onion"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to merge the second array items to the first one using the `jq` command.

If I do the following

```
jq -c < file.json
```

I receive

```json
{"fruits":[{"name":"banana"},{"name":"apple"}],"vegtabels":[{"name":"tomato"},{"name":"onion"}]}
```

I want to receive

```json
{"fruits":[{"name":"banana"},{"name":"apple"},{"name":"tomato"},{"name":"onion"}]}
```

How can I achieve that?
Can I control the merge by the array name? If I will have more arrays on that object?

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate over all second-level items using `.[][]`, and collect them into an array using the array constructor `[…]`:

```bash
jq -c '{fruits: [.[][]]}'
```

```json
{"fruits":[{"name":"banana"},{"name":"apple"},{"name":"tomato"},{"name":"onion"}]}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/TCd6IdGiPfW)

If you don't know the field name, you could, for instance, use `keys_unsorted[0]` to fetch the name of the first key (first in this representation order): `{(keys_unsorted[0]): [.[][]]}` [Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/-Rva_LgpxKd)

Answer (score 1):

Several alternatives:

```
.fruits += .vegetables | del(.vegetables)
```

```
{ fruits: (.fruits + .vegetables) }
```

```
{ fruits: map(.[]) }
```

Comment: You forgot the simplest one: `{fruits: flatten}`

Comment: @pmf sure, feel free to add that to your own answer (instead of `[.[][]]`)